# The MySQL trigger in Zapier does not trigger

Tags: mysql, api, triggers

Unfortunately, my trigger does not fire (New or Updated Row in MySQL).
I have the following settings: when an appointment becomes binding the trigger should fire, but unfortunately it does not work.
Thanks for the help!
[image]

How can I solve this problem?